# Nunjucks nested loop not rendering properly

Tags: html, yaml, nunjucks

I'm trying to create an unordered list with listitems in nunjucks based on the content of a YML file.

```
context:
  top:
    - list:
        - item:
          text: Hello
    - list:
        - item:
          text: Hello
```

```
  <div>
    {% for list in top %}
    <ul>
      {% for item in list %}
      <li>{{ item.text }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

The unordered lists are rendered, the listitems aren't. Maybe there is an issue with the indentation of the YML file, but i cant figure it out. Thanks.